# post receive hook is showing an error of permission

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I am trying to push the code into a beta directory as a developer pushed the code from their local system. So I made a file inside hooks post-receive and give them sufficient permission, it gets execute but throwing an error of

> remote: fatal: Could not switch to 'path-to-beta-dir': Permission
>   denied To user@ip:/path-to-repo 46bbd50..787b266  master -> master

Answer (score 0):

Check path-to-beta-dir permissions and ownership.Try changing them.Give to your user as owner or give permissions with chmod for read and write.
If you still getting an error check the user's home directory permissions in /home/ if only root has permission try changing them.
You can give x to others for e.x. and try ("chmod 0701 /home/your_user").